# Laravel Forge - Redirect Loop - SSL and Load balancer

Tags: laravel, nginx

I just set up 3 servers with laravel forge.
1 load balancer and 2 file servers that contains my laravel project.

I have installed my SSL-certificate on all three servers, and pointed my domain to the load balancer servers IP Address.

However, when accessing my sites url now, I get a redirect loop.
Anyone got any suggestions?

Here is the config for the load balancer (Domain removed for question):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.no;
    return 301 https://mydomain.no$request_uri;
}

include upstreams/mydomain.no;

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name .mydomain.no;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.no/16768/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.no/16768/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    charset utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mydomain.no-error.log error;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://116816_app/;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # Handle Web Socket connections
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

And here is the nginx conf from my file servers:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.no;
    return 301 https://mydomain.no$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name .mydomain.no;
    root /home/forge/mydomain.no/httpdocs/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.no/16782/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.no/16782/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mydomain.no-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.no;
    return 301 https://mydomain.no$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name .mydomain.no;
    root /home/forge/mydomain.no/httpdocs/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.no/16783/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.no/16783/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mydomain.no-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are connecting to your upstream using the `http` scheme. This causes it to redirect to `https`, which the load balancer then routes upstream using `http`. Hence the loop.

Either connect upstream using `https`:

```
proxy_pass https://116816_app/;
```

Or allow your upstream file server to accept connections using `http`:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ...
}
```